# How can I sync places between iPhone and computer?

Tags: iphone, applications, data-synchronization, google-maps, network

I'm looking for a way to drop pins on the map from my computer and have those pins accessible on my iPhone.

I know Maps app has Bookmarks but it appears I can't sync them with Google account or anything. Can I achieve this functionality, with or without third-party apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google Places](http://www.google.com/places/) does exactly that.

[image: Google Places web]

You can manage places through web interface or the iPhone app.
Places marked with a star (**Saved for later**) will be displayed in **Saved** section in the app:

[image: Google Places app]

You can rate and review places from the app as well.